vs code auto-suggestion for next.js is not working and, nextjs project made by create-next-app not working correctly
the auto-suggestions in vscode for nextjs for example: className for any element, or placeholder for input or src of next Image component are not showing up for a newly create next.js app using create-next-app with javascript.

This I can live with but even the imports are not working correctly, usually in a client component when I import usestate it comes from "react" but now I'm getting these "react/cjs/react.production.min" or "react/cjs/react.development"

and finally, when I add a client component in the page.js (Home component). I get the error in layout.js that
You are attempting to export "metadata" from a component marked with "use client", which is disallowed. Either remove the export, or the "use client" directive
even though the layout page doesn't have a "use client" in it anywhere, and when I remove the client component it works fine. I'm not even adding the client component directly in the layout page
for the auto-suggestions I tried to enable and disable the checkjs in settings, I restarted some extensions like eslint, ES7 react snippets, I asked chat gpt it told me to change the jsconfig, none of these worked. I've tried to make a new nextjs project still the same issues (suggestions, imports, client component), I even tried it in a react project, but no suggestions.
React and React-dom are version 18, and next is version 14.2.15, and I also tried the 14.2.2
still no change
